# Email Piping and PHP

Tags: php, email

I'm currently trying to get some help desk software set up and it has the functionality to pipe emails to a PHP script. We use a Microsoft exchange server for our emails while the website and the PHP script to pipe to is hosted on a separate IIS server.

All the examples I've seen of this being done have the email and website hosted on the same server making it easy to pipe the email to the PHP file. In my case I need to pipe the email to a file that is on our domain but a different server. Is this possible?

Comment: This is possible, but it's going to get very complicated. Are the servers on the same local network?

Comment: @DaveRandom They're on the same Domain and yes they are on the same network.

Comment: The domain isn't really relevant here since you're going to have to write at least one and possibly two bits of middleware to get the job done. Here's what I'm thinking: use an Exchange event sink (scriptable in VBS, I understand that newer versions also let you write full .net apps as well, I haven't made one since Exch 2003 though) to fetch the email content programmatically. Then post it to the web server (probably via HTTP would be sensible) and have the webserver invoke the script provided by the helpdesk and pipe the mail content into it. Like I say, possible, but complicated.

Comment: An alternative might be to set up a mail server that is capable of doing native piping on the web server (access controlled with a firewall, of course) and just configure exchange to forward the incoming mail address in question to that server.

Comment: Gah that does sound like hard work, doesn't help I don't have clearance for the email server. Its just as we are hosting the site internally but would still like any external users to still be able to contact our help desk system. I'm wondering if its worth the time coding it but thanks for helping me get an idea of the requirements.

Comment: I'd go with setting up an email server on the web server but it's my bosses call. Appreciate the help Dave!

Comment: This is turning into a lengthy discussion not appropriate for comments, if you want to discuss it further you can find me in [the PHP chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) :-)

Comment: That would be a fine idea if I had the reputation :P never-mind mate it doesn't look like I'm going to get much done on this today so I'll get on with some other projects. You've been a great help!

Comment: OK no worries, you should only need 20 rep to talk in chat, and I'm usually around in that room for at least a few hours a day so you know where to find me. I suggest you leave this question open for the time being in case anyone else has any bright ideas, I might take a look at implementing this later to see how hard it is. What version of Exchange are you using?

Comment: I think we're on 2010, Looks like i do have rep. I'm on 67 I was just looking at the my 6 badges :S having one of those days